# Extending EntityType to access Entity

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'd like access to the instance of the entity when using an `EntityType::class`. I have a form like below:

```
->add('fooBars', MyNewType::class, [
    'class' => FooBar::class,
    'choices' => $fooBars,
    'label' => 'Foo Bar',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'by_reference' => false,
]);
```

I've created a new type which has the parent of entity type, I then have a custom template as well. Having followed [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) I have my entity type displaying but where I'm looping over the children, I don't know how to access the entity.

```
{% block foo_bar_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if expanded %}
            <ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                {% for child in form if not child.rendered %}
                    <li>
                        {{ form_widget(child) }}
                        {{ form_label(child) }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            {{ block('choice_widget') }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'd like to call a method on the entity it's looping over but I'm unsure how to access it. I can't dump child as it produces too much.

Comment: Why do you want do to that? Why not use `child.data`?

Comment: @NicoHaase I get the following error: Neither the property "data" nor one of the methods "data()", "getdata()"/"isdata()"/"hasdata()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

Comment: Sorry - you could try to use `child.value`

Comment: @NicoHaase Same error as above. I can't see what I have access to from `child` as I can't dump it which is annoying. I have managed to get data from `child.vars` but nothing related to my entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the following:

```
{% set entity = form.vars.choices[child.vars.value].data %}
```

So the complete block may look like:

```
{% block foo_bar_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if expanded %}
            <ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                {% for child in form if not child.rendered %}
                    {% set entity = form.vars.choices[child.vars.value].data %}

                    <li>
                        {{ form_widget(child) }}
                        {{ form_label(child) }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            {{ block('choice_widget') }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

And now you can call entity methods like so:

```
{{ entity.name }}}
```